# SISS - Problems to convert DT_STR to DT_DECIMAL (decimals going to integer part number)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion, decimal, etl

I´m using SSIS on VS 2015, and I make a test using OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination (tables on SQL Server 2017). The problem is the Source table I have the one field varchar(10) type and the values is decimal´s (remember that this field is varchar(10).

[image]

The values TB_ are:

[image]

On Integration Services, I used OLE DB Source, Data Conversion and OLE DB Destination.

[image]

On Data Conversion Component, I set the type to numeric (and decimal I tried after):

[image]

On OLE DB Destination, I mapped the fields:

[image]

But, when I execute the Package, The OLE DB Destination have the values:

[image]

The correct values on CAMPO2 field will be 4.51, 20.5 and 98.54

The struct table OLE DB Destination is:

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that SSIS read Windows Regional Configuration. I used "," comma instead point, and SSIS worked very well.

On Expression Builder, I used:
(DT_DECIMAL,2)[CAMPO2]

(Not need to replace ",")

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem cause

The main cause is the decimal seperator, the varchar column contains a comma `,` instead of a point `.`

#### Experiments

If we try to case the following text to decimal `"1,2"` the result is:

> 12.00

[image]

If we try to case the following text to decimal `"1.2"` the result is:

> 1.20

[image]

#### Solution

Instead of using Data Conversion transformation, try using a Derived column with the following expression:

```
(DT_DECIMAL,2)REPLACE([CAMPO2],",",".")
```